# How do you force a job to prompt the user for variables in a parallel pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a very basic Gitlab CICD yaml file that is supposed to run two jobs on completion of another job. I'd like one job to automatically set a variable, while the other job prompts the user to define one. These jobs are called `auto` and `manual` respectively. However, when I run the file below, the `manual` step just doesn't set anything and continues to run without prompting  the user for variables. This does make sense, but how exactly do I force this job to prompt the user for variable definitions?

```
stages:
- A
- B

.template
  script:
    - echo ${MY_VARIABLE}

setup:
  stage: A
  script:
    - echo "do nothing yet"
  allow_failure: false
  when: manual

auto:
  stage: B
  variables:
    MY_VARIABLE: "I am automatically set"
  when: on_success
  dependencies:
    - setup

manual:
  stage: B
  when: manual
  dependencies:
    - setup
```

Currently, the above results in:

`auto` output

```
I am automatically set
```

`manual` output

What I want:
[image]

UPDATE: It doesn't look like there is a way to force the above.